# auto accepting rsa key in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

Is there a way to auto accept any RSA key inside a bash script with no user interference? I need this script to run without user intervention and it will stop every time it encounters a new ip, i just need it to accept all of them.

Comment: What command is being run in the bash script? You may want to look at twinpipe or expect.

http://bisqwit.iki.fi/source/twinpipe.html
http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If all you need is to accept new unknown hosts, try this:

```
 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

If you also need to accept changed host keys, you can trick SSH into using a blank file for storing it's local set of known host keys, then accepting new unknown ones. Note this is a Bad Idea™:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```